# Notification for android: what is different between notification and data payload

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

It looks the same with the payload i used either notification or data

```
{"notification":{"body":"Notification Hub test notification"}}
```

I thought notification payload can still receive notification even it was closed not backgrounded or foreground. I tried it but not seems to receive the payload  when app was inactive.

It seems both data and notification i received the same result

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Cloud Messaging supports two types of messages, notification message and data message. The difference between them is that with data message you can send your own data elements in the message where as with notification message you have to use predefined elements.

As names suggest, notification message type is used to send notifications which will be displayed as notifications in the notification bar. FCM automatically handles notification messages and your app can also process it and customize it. Data message type is used to send data to client. Your app has to process it and take further action. There is restriction of 4kb on the size of message that can be sent to client.

**Notification message in JSON format**

```
{"message":{"topic":"deals","notification":{"body":"View latest deals from top brands.","title":"Latest Deals"}}}
```

**Data message in JSON format**

```
{"message":{"topic":"deals","data":{"storeNAME":"Nordstorm","deal":"Get upto 50% off on Shoes","dealDesc":"Get upto 50% off on branded shoes.","expiry":"20180110","code":"NORDSH"}}}
```

**Notification and data message in JSON format**

```
{"message":{"topic":"deals","data":{"storeNAME":"Nordstorm","deal":"Get upto 50% off on Shoes","dealDesc":"Get upto 50% off on branded shoes.","expiry":"20180110","code":"NORDSH"},"notification":{"body":"View latest deals from top brands.","title":"Latest Deals"}}}
```

Note that in the data message, only name and value pairs are allowed under data element, meaning data element can’t have hierarchical data or JSON array.

Comment: To add some more context Notification Payload are handled by the OS whereas Data Payload is not you need to manually handle it in your service.

Answer (score 3):

The notification payload is automatically handled by the OS when the app is backgrounded. The data payload is always delivered to your application code.